# How to Toggle Animate Element Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, repeat

I have a jQuery like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#title").click(function(){                
             $(this).animate({left:'30px'});                
       });
 });
```

my question is, is it possible to return the jQuery element to the initial position upon clicking for the second time, and back to left:'30px' when it's clicked for the third time, and so on... ?

Answer (score 2):

[***Demo playground***](http://jsbin.com/odobab/5/edit)

```
  // /////////  
  // EXAMPLE 1 
  // Toggle variable value (1,0,1,0...) using Modulo (%) operator

  var c = 0;
  $("#el").click(function(){
      $(this).animate({left: ++c%2 * 50 });                
  });
```

```
  // /////////
  // EXAMPLE 2
  // Read current position and use Conditional Operator (?:) 

  $("#el").click(function(){
      var leftAt0 = this.offsetLeft < 1 ; // Boolean (true if at 0px left)
      $(this).animate({left: leftAt0 ? 50 : 0 });                
  });
```

```
  // /////////
  // EXAMPLE 3
  // Toggle two values using array.reverse method

  var pos = [0, 50];
  $("#el").click(function(){
      $(this).animate({left: pos.reverse()[0] });                
  });
```

Comment: yes I didn't see the demo. I'm sorry,anyway I'm confused, could you please explain me how that's possible ? I wonder how to set the distance. the distance of the movement doesn't fit with what I wanted

Comment: in my code `30` is your desired distance. have you wrapped the code into a document ready function like I did in the demo link ( `$(function(){ /*code here*/ });` ) ?

Comment: Do you have the correct CSS to support the animation? Note how in the demo roXon has position: relative set? That's critical for this to work...by default the title won't move if its left value is set.

Comment: For an example, check out http://jsfiddle.net/JwFsC/4/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/JwFsC/5/ (in the second example, I've commented out the CSS that makes it work).

Comment: lol, sure you need a position, have you seen in my demo? I have set an element `position` too. otherwise use `marginLeft` instead of `left`

Comment: @EdwinLimantara :) was that clear? you just disappeared, if you don't understand something feel free to ask, we're here to help

Comment: @roXon thank you, you're very kind, I am a bit confused. I've to do something right now, I will follow up with that after I get back.

Comment: @dodgerblue have you followed up the problem? I added some new examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#title").click(function(){
   var $this = $(this)
   $this.animate({left:$this.position().left ? 0 : '30px'});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#title").click(function() {
             $(this).animate({ left: '30px' }, function(e) {
                 $(this).animate({
                     left: '-=30px'
                 });
             });
         });
```